# Run application in emulator?

Tags: android

When I'm going to run my application a new emulator starts, despite that I already have an emulator opened! Since the time to load and launch the emulator is so long, isn't there a way to run an application in a emulator that is already opened? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the property of ur app as manual rather than automatic to run an application..

Just right click on the app, then Run->RunConfiguration->Target->Manual

So by doing this, whenever you run ur application,it first ask you at which emulator,you want ur application to run..

Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I have selected Manul, I get an Android Device Chooser where I'm going to choose a running Android device, but there is non to select, despite that I have an emulator opened?!

Comment: @3D-kreativ Make sure the target version in manifest and the device version are the same

Comment: Then you must close and reopen ur emulator. It must be shown in the running device if it is opened

Comment: The emulator will not launch! I get some strange window about the visual studio just-in-time debugger! The window want me to select either "Set the currently selected debugger as the default" or "Manually choose the debugger engine. In the title of the window it says: An unhandled win32 exception occurred in emulator-arm-exe[3976] !? I don't know what to do? And I must leave the computer for some time and hopefully I can solve this problem later. Thanks!

Comment: The problem was gone for now when I created a new emulator

Answer (score 0):

please right click on project from eclipse and then select "Run As >> Run Configuration " 
this will appear one dialog from this dialog select "Target tab" then click on "Manually"  option button.
after then click on run button this will ask every time to select emulator to run project

enjoy ..

Answer (score 0):

To choose the target each time (this is annoying usually)

1. Go to the Run configurations of the project:
2. Go to the Target tab and choose manual

---

To make ***running a new AVD faster***:

1. Go to AVD manager
2. Edit the AVD you want to make faster
3. check **Enabled for Snapshot**